# AngularJS cannot successfully call WebAPI but Fiddler does?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am pretty new to AngularJS. I am trying out $http.

I created a very simple WebAPI to test. Below is the code:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] product = new Product[]
       {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Fruit" },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo"},
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer"}
       };

    public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        return Ok(new { results = product as IEnumerable<Product> });
    }
}
```

When I try to access using Fiddler, it properly returns JSON. But when I try using this working example here: http://embed.plnkr.co/lrn0NNMNbIVE4rS4Fytd/preview

And call http://localhost:55403/api/products (I change the properties in the option value to match the Products), it doesn't even go there.

It seems to go to the onFetchError.

Does it mean that the WebAPI is not returning JSON as expected?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error msg in fetcherror?

Comment: I figured it out; it was a CORS issue. I just allowed my dummy WebAPI for cross domain access.